# How can I know if the user clicked on a button or an another part of the screen

Tags: android, button, click, focus

I got a OnClickListener with some Button. So, when I press some of that buttons appear at bottom of the screen another Button, for example. If I dont click that last Button, this one must disappear.

The question is: how can I know if the user clicked on a button or an another part of the screen.

If the user clicked the button I can use onClick()?
If the user didnt click the button, what function get that action?

PD:I tried with onUserInteraction() and cant resolve this, because the program call it clicked or not the button.

---

My XML code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/paco"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/pepe"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp" >
            </RelativeLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </FrameLayout>

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp" >

            </TabWidget>

        </FrameLayout>

    </TabHost>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pedro"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutCuadricula_anadirRegalo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btCuadricula_foto"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Foto" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btCuadricula_galeria"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btCuadricula_foto"
                android:text="Galeria" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btCuadricula_iconos"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btCuadricula_galeria"
                android:text="Iconos" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btCuadricula_anadir"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Añadir" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Well, when I press the Button "Añadir" appear the RelativeLayout with another 3 Buttons. If my next action is not press any of that buttons the RelativeLayout.

I show my code:

```
  public class Cuadricula extends TabActivity implements OnClickListener {
        private Button btAnadir, btFoto, btGaleria, btIcono;
        private AlphaAnimation alpha;
        private TranslateAnimation translate;
        private RelativeLayout cuadroBotones;
        private AnimationSet animationSet;
        private LinearLayout pedro;
        private FrameLayout pepe, paco;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cuadricula); 


    pedro = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.pedro);
    pepe = (FrameLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.pepe);
    paco = (FrameLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.paco);



    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    TabSpec primeraPestana = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
    TabSpec segundaPestana = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid2");
    TabSpec terceraPestana = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid3");
    TabSpec cuartaPestana = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid4");

    primeraPestana.setIndicator("Timeline").setContent(
            new Intent(this, Timeline.class));
    segundaPestana.setIndicator("Eventos").setContent(
            new Intent(this, Personas.class));
    terceraPestana.setIndicator("Perfil").setContent(
            new Intent(this, Perfil.class));
    cuartaPestana.setIndicator("Top").setContent(
            new Intent(this, Top.class));

    tabHost.addTab(primeraPestana);
    tabHost.addTab(segundaPestana);
    tabHost.addTab(terceraPestana);
    tabHost.addTab(cuartaPestana);

    cuadroBotones = (RelativeLayout) this
            .findViewById(R.id.layoutCuadricula_anadir);
    cuadroBotones.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.GONE);

    btFoto = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btCuadricula_foto);
    btGaleria = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btCuadricula_galeria);
    btIcono = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btCuadricula_iconos);
    btAnadir = (Button) this
            .findViewById(R.id.btCuadricula_anadirRegalo);

    btFoto.setOnClickListener(this);
    btGaleria.setOnClickListener(this);
    btIcono.setOnClickListener(this);
    btAnadir.setOnClickListener(this);
    paco.setOnClickListener(this);
    pedro.setOnClickListener(this);
    pepe.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Transiciones del cuadro de botones
    alpha = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    alpha.setDuration(1000);
    alpha.setFillAfter(true); // Tell it to persist after the animation ends

    translate = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0);
    translate.setDuration(500);

    animationSet = new AnimationSet(true);
    animationSet.addAnimation(alpha);
    animationSet.addAnimation(translate);

}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btCuadricula_anadirRegalo:
        cuadroBotones.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.INVISIBLE);
        cuadroBotones.startAnimation(animationSet);
        botonesDesplegados = true;
        break;
    case R.id.btCuadricula_foto:
        break;
    case R.id.btCuadricula_galeria:
        break;
    case R.id.btCuadricula_iconos:
        break;
    case R.id.LinearLayout1:
    case R.id.paco:
    case R.id.pepe:
    case R.id.pedro:
        cuadroBotones.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.GONE);
        break;
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put an onClickListener on anything that derives from View, so you can do this on the layout that contains your buttons, for example.  If a View within your layout doesn't have an onClickListener itself or returns false from onClick, the click event will keep tunneling down until it is caught by your layout's onClick.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an onclick method to the screen. For example, if you use a frameview on a relative layout, and keep it behind everything else, you can certainly get onclick from the frame view.

Answer (score 0):

All your views are located within a linear layout. You can simply add an onClick event for this linear layout and when clicked anywhere in the screen (except on other views), the event will be raised.